# Is Oracle Unbreakable linux free?Why ask for certificate?

Tags: oracle-linux

Is this distribution free like Fedora,Centos,etc?
I have installed Firefox on Oracle Unbreakable Linux and it open a webpage
when it ask me for get a new CA certificate.
The CA certificate Require an oracle login(free) and a customer support identifier (CSI) which is not free.

[image]

Comment: Please give more information, be exact: What certificate from which CA is requested?

Comment: It tell me that sha1 is deprecated and new sha256 CA is avaliable,but need support contract to get the certificate

Comment: FAO of other close-vote reviewers: while this question may be somewhat unclear, it's *not* a request for learning materials and should not be closed for that reason. See https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3892/22812

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To quote the [Oracle Linux Premier Support](https://shop.oracle.com/apex/f?p=DSTORE:PRODUCT:::NO:RP,6:P6_LPI:4510277002891805728469) page:

> All Oracle Linux software is provided for free and can be downloaded from Oracle Software Delivery Cloud.

That seems to answer your question fairly directly.  Some features (such as Ksplice) require a support contract, but the cost model is similar to that of Solaris: you pay for a support contract (and possibly features), not for the software itself.

---

As to your certificate issue, the ULN updated to SHA-256 at the end of 2016. The alert message appears to be static text on the homepage, and does not necessarily reflect the status of your system. If you do not get further errors regarding the certificate, then the one on your system is up to date and there is nothing more you need to do.

If you do find that your system has the old certificate, [the FAQ](https://linux.oracle.com/uln_faq.html) includes a sequence of steps to update to the new one:

```
# cp /usr/share/rhn/ULN-CA-CERT /usr/share/rhn/ULN-CA-CERT.old
# wget https://linux-update.oracle.com/rpms/ULN-CA-CERT.sha2
# cp ULN-CA-CERT.sha2 /usr/share/rhn/ULN-CA-CERT
```

I have not verified that these are the correct paths for recent Oracle Linux installations, but I have verified that the `wget` portion works even on non-Oracle systems.